# Article selection before the first appearance of a term

Tags: articles

I am in the process of writing a documentation for a software project. I would like to understand what would be the best article to use at the beginning of the first sentence in the description of a software library.

For example, consider the following hypothetical (first sentence):

> The report presents an outline of **a/the** C++ class library named LIBNAME that provides a unified interface for encapsulation and automation of execution of a variety of algorithms.

What would be the best article to use in this case?

Comment: A possible alternative: ***This** report presents an outline of **LIBNAME, a C++ class library** that provides a unified interface for encapsulation and automation of execution of a variety of algorithms.*

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59725/do-we-use-an-article-before-a-name-that-refers-to-a-technique-or-an-algorithm/59735#59735 . In this case, 'a C++ class library named' rather than 'the C++ class library named' reads more naturally to me.'

Comment: @amblina - You might put this as an answer! (0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The* is used to signal that we are talking about a specific noun mentioned previously conversation/context, or observable by those in the conversation.  *A/an X* is used to signal that we mean *any of X* and not a specific *X* mentioned earlier.

Some nouns are considered "observable" by others by default, especially if the noun is a big thing that affects/impacts everyone, or is considered well known by everyone.  Examples include *the sky*, *the ground*, etc.

Context can control what is "considered well known by everyone."  In this case, your sentence is talking about a C library and I'm assuming part of the target audience for your text are likely programmers.

So, regarding "C++ class library named LIBNAME":

- Is this a well-known standard library that any C programmer should have heard of?  Such as `<stdio>`?  Use *the* in that case.  If you are addressing non-programmers though, they may think they have missed something, or feel left out.
- Should the reader have heard of this library before, perhaps in earlier chapters or earlier volumes of the text?  Then, use *the*.
- If this is not a well-known library by your target audience, and you introducing to the reader to it, then it cannot be "mentioned previously" or "observable" and you should use *a* to talk about it the first time.  Afterward, you use *the* to talk about it.

This assumes this is the first sentence that mentions LIBNAME.

Now, is your book titled "LIBNAME"?  Do you have a chapter title visible above this text that says "All About LIBNAME" or similar?  Some writers might consider that as "previously mentioned," and would use *the* based on that.  That's OK too.